# PHP text parsing and / or make your own language?

Tags: php, parsing, nlp, dsl

Been Googling around without finding much at all, so does anyone know of a class or library that helps you parse any sort of language, like a [Domain Specific Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_programming_language) (I'm creating one, so I'm flexible in what the syntax and format can be) into either PHP code or some helpful struct or a class hiearchy or ... ? Anything goes at this point. :)

I want to experiment with parsing text files into tokens, building up a small grammar and syntax library to express things like [Business Natural Languages](http://bnl.jayfields.com/01_introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with BNF style input syntax, you should look at:

http://pear.php.net/PHP_ParserGenerator

or

http://pear.php.net/PHP_LexerGenerator

The PHP code they generate is a little disturbing, but it works, and is a good head-start for some parser tasks.